# Conditional prepared statements PHP mysqli, reduce

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli, prepared-statement

it works but I don't feel like it's the best solution for my problem.
What I want my code to do is to check if the location = 1 and send the messages for all of the locations.

```
function getCurrentMessage($location){
    $conn = Connection::getConnection();

    if($location == 1) {
        $query = "SELECT first_name, last_name, description, title, message ,font_size , effective_date 
                FROM tbl_messages
                JOIN tbl_authors ON tbl_authors.id_author = tbl_messages.id_author 
                JOIN tbl_locations ON tbl_messages.id_location = tbl_locations.id_location
                AND effective_date <= CURDATE()
                ORDER BY effective_date desc
                LIMIT 2;";

        $result = array();

        if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {
            $stmt->bind_result($first_name, $last_name, $location, $title, $message, $size, $date);
            $stmt->execute();

            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                $message = new Message($first_name, $last_name, $location, $title, $message, $size, $date);
                array_push($result, $message);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        $query = "SELECT first_name, last_name, description, title, message ,font_size , effective_date 
                FROM tbl_messages
                JOIN tbl_authors ON tbl_authors.id_author = tbl_messages.id_author 
                JOIN tbl_locations ON tbl_messages.id_location = tbl_locations.id_location
                WHERE tbl_messages.id_location = ?
                AND effective_date <= CURDATE()
                ORDER BY effective_date desc
                LIMIT 2;";

        $result = array();

        if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {
            $stmt->bind_result($first_name, $last_name, $location, $title, $message, $size, $date);
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $location);
            $stmt->execute();

            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                $m = new Message($first_name, $last_name, $location, $title, $message, $size, $date);
                array_push($result, $m);
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Maybe I could put some logic in the SQL statement.
If you have any insight please help.

Comment: you can remove the check for location at the beginning of the function. This would help by allowing use only one query. THen have a where clause which would take the location from the parameter in the function like `WHERE location=?`

Comment: [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be the best place to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize now that this question should have been posted in code review [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) 
,
but after learning more about MYSQL I figured a way to clean up the code so here is my answer using Control Flow Functions.
If you have any other idea to further clean up the code please tell me.

```
$conn = getConnection();
$query = "SELECT first_name, last_name, description, title, message ,font_size , DATE_FORMAT(effective_date,'%h:%i %p %m-%d-%Y')
          FROM tbl_messages
          JOIN tbl_authors ON tbl_authors.id_author = tbl_messages.id_author
          JOIN tbl_locations ON tbl_messages.id_location = tbl_locations.id_location
          WHERE tbl_messages.id_location = IF(? = 1,tbl_messages.id_location,?)
          AND effective_date <= NOW()
          ORDER BY effective_date DESC
          LIMIT 1
          ";

if (!$stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {
    return false;
}

$stmt->bind_param('ii', $location,$location);

$result = array();

$stmt->bind_result($first_name, $last_name, $location, $title, $message, $size, $date);
$stmt->execute();

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $m = new Message($first_name, $last_name, $location, $title, $message, $size, $date);
    array_push($result, $m);
}

return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just refactor out all the duplicate parts that don't depend on the  conditions.

```
function getCurrentMessage($location){
    $conn = Connection::getConnection();

    if($location == 1) {
        $query = "SELECT first_name, last_name, description, title, message ,font_size , effective_date 
                FROM tbl_messages
                JOIN tbl_authors ON tbl_authors.id_author = tbl_messages.id_author 
                JOIN tbl_locations ON tbl_messages.id_location = tbl_locations.id_location
                AND effective_date <= CURDATE()
                ORDER BY effective_date desc
                LIMIT 2;";

        if (!$stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {
            return false;
        }

    }
    else{
        $query = "SELECT first_name, last_name, description, title, message ,font_size , effective_date 
                FROM tbl_messages
                JOIN tbl_authors ON tbl_authors.id_author = tbl_messages.id_author 
                JOIN tbl_locations ON tbl_messages.id_location = tbl_locations.id_location
                WHERE tbl_messages.id_location = ?
                AND effective_date <= CURDATE()
                ORDER BY effective_date desc
                LIMIT 2;";

        if (!$stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {
            return false;
        }
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $location);
    }

    $result = array();

    $stmt->bind_result($first_name, $last_name, $location, $title, $message, $size, $date);
    $stmt->execute();

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
         $m = new Message($first_name, $last_name, $location, $title, $message, $size, $date);
         array_push($result, $m);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

You could go even further, but this is just a sample.  Note how the function returns false if statement preparation fails.  Since you're inside a function, this will just stop execution of that function and return false since there is no point of going further if preparation fails.  You could also use exceptions if you want something that can be caught.